# Laravel Fortify login y registro en la misma página

Tags: autenticación, laravel-8, registro

Cuando intento ubicar los formularios de login y registro en la misma página surgen conflictos, es decir, si hay errores en el registro, estos aparecen en el formulario del login y no funciona bien, [hay soluciones](https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-login-and-register-forms-on-the-same-page/) que cambian el nombre de los campos en uno de los formularios y modifican la validación con los nuevos campos, esto funciona bien en versiones antiguas de Laravel, pero con Fortify cambia todo.

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que has intentado por favor

Comment: He intentado lo que hay en el link que he compartido y no funciona, no hace nada, ni siquiera da error.

Comment: Para poderte ayudar aqui en la comunidad requerimos un [mcve], te recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: Lo he leído, pero no veo el sentido de compartir un código que no funciona, la respuesta que espero no se basa en código si no en cómo afrontar el problema ya que con ese código, por esa vía, nadie me va a poder ayudar, de todas formas muchas gracias.

Comment: La idea es ayudarte sobre algo que hayas intentado, ya que de lo contrario tu pregunta quedará cerrada, no hablo de que copies aquí el código de la publicación (*ese solo debe quedar como referencia*) sino que pongas el mínimo necesario para saber que hiciste tu y como trataste de configurar fortify y poder tratar de dar una respuesta

Comment: Es que hice lo mismo que en el artículo, esto es un sin sentido, cierra y a vivir.